# Search seems too accent-sensitive

Tags: feature-request, bug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Search is too accent-sensitive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133336/search-is-too-accent-sensitive)

> Cross-posted to [Meta.SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/133336/165502).

A search for `que` does not show results for `qué`.  I think this makes the site less usable--especially for Spanish beginners.

Can the search engine be modified to not be "accent-sensitive"? (Is that a real term?)

Comment: I'm going to boldly call this a bug. Google search handles extraneous and missing accents and more because for some languages it's really necessary. Adding the "bug" tag.

Comment: Even the [Diccionario de la Real Academia Española](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/) has the option to ignore diacritics on a word search.

Answer (score 6):

This is definitely a bug, and databases like SQL Server support accent-insensitive collations without a problem (yes, it is a real term).

As noted by hippietrail, that's how searches in Google work too.

Also, many people learning Spanish might not be using the International keyboard layout, placing an additional burden on entering those terms in the first place.

Comment: We know the Stack Exchange software has some knowledge of accents / diacritics, because it strips them to make the URL from the question title and removes them if you try to use them in tags. So this should just be a little bit more fun for them to implement (-:

Answer (score 4):

This is seriously important and needs to be brought up to the Jeff-Joel executive level at StackExchange.  You can't be putting up language sites without a search function that works well in different languages.

Have the German site people worked on this? There are 107 hits for *über* and 2 for *uber*.

I tried the Japanese site and *せんせん* finds nothing while *ぜんぜん* gets some hits, but I bet people find that somewhat different (not as much as you'd think if you're not already an expert!).

Comment: If you really feel it's going unnoticed here, feel free to ask a parallel version of the question on meta.stackoverlow - but be prepared for some hostility there from some regulars. Or maybe it's already been asked there...

Comment: I asked about posting this on meta.SO, and was told by an SE employee that this was completely unnecessary, as the powers that be would see this; and that she would point it out to them as well.  No doubt moving it to meta.SO would generate more up-votes, but up-votes aren't really what we're after :)