# Ignore American and British English spelling differences

Tags: feature-request, search

This is network-wide, I'll demonstrate with dba.SE

[Searching for *localisation*](https://dba.stackexchange.com/search?q=localisation) gives 5 results: *localisation*, *localised*, *localisation*, *localised* and *localisation*

[Searching for *localization*](https://dba.stackexchange.com/search?q=localization) gives 2481 results, *localization* appears but also words like *local*, *locale*, *locally*.

Searching for *color* and *colour* also gives different results.

Can the configuration be tweaked to ignore [American and British English spelling differences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_and_British_English_spelling_differences)?

Comment: To be clear, if you search for 'colour', you also want everything with 'color', correct? (and the reverse, of course)

Comment: @TimPost correct. Likewise, if I search for 'localisation' I also want to see the results I would get from searching for 'localization'.

Comment: ...except on EL&U, where it might be significant.

Comment: Zomeone zhould write a uzerzcript that juzt putz zeez where they belongz.

Comment: Why not simply auto-correct all "American English" words into their proper English equivalents? :)

Comment: @Shog9 I can't pronounce "zhould" correctly. You ruined my day.

Comment: Related: [Search is too accent-sensitive](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/133336/167646)

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes. I think /zh/ is commonly used in simple phonetics to indicate the sound in the middle of *leisure*.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit. While I tend to write *-ise* myself, out of force of habit, I actually prefer *-ize*. It's also favoured by Oxford.

Comment: @TRiG OUP is the _only_ English publication to do so.

Comment: I've had this issue too lately, since I typically use a lot of UK spellings, such as *colour*, *programme*, and -*ise*. This post hasn't seen any activity for almost a year now. Have there been any updates on fixing this?