# Chat doesn't onebox meta.se comments with newsletter code in the URL

Tags: bug, comments, chat, onebox

I don't know whether this is network-wide or just on SO, but chat doesn't onebox meta.se comments when I've come to the post through the Meta newsletter and so `?newsletter=1&nlcode=x` is in the URL

It should!

i.e.

```
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236552/ignore-american-and-british-
english-spelling-differences?newsletter=1&nlcode=83%7ca920#comment775901_236552
```

vs

```
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236552/ignore-american-and-british-
english-spelling-differences#comment775901_236552
```

It took us a while in the Lounge to figure this one out, which therefore must be deemed to violate the principle of least surprise.

Comment: POLS? Sorry, but can you spell that out?

Comment: @Oded: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment

Comment: Ah. Familiar with the principle, not the acronym.

Comment: Also breaks for lots of other querystrings. The one for duplicate / related links is particularly annoying in this regard.

Comment: @Shog9 the related link one should now be fixed; comments is trickier - looking

Comment: This acts differently now. The onebox occurs, but it results in the question being oneboxed, not the linked comment! Only noticed it today; it could be new behaviour from, off the top of my head, the last week or so?