# Oneboxing doesn't work for questions from Related/Linked panel

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, related-questions, onebox

As the title says. How to reproduce:

1. Open any question.
2. Click any question in the Linked / Related right panels:

   [image]
3. Copy-paste the link into the chat.

It doesn't work because the link address is ended by `?lq=1` or `?rq=1`, which confuses the One-boxer. I suggest making the one-boxer ignore these GET parameters.

Comment: Related or dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236681/chat-doesnt-onebox-meta-se-comments-with-newsletter-code-in-the-url

Comment: @ShadowWizard related; not dupe - as evidenced that fixing one does not fix the other

Comment: @Marc wasn't sure, since both are due to querystring parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fair enough; should be fixed in a few minutes

Comment: So you have white list of allowed querystring parameters, or do you ignore any querystring now?

Comment: @ShadowWizard I'm just ignoring the query-string here; we don't need it, and it isn't used in the final render

Comment: Works like charm, you're our hero! :)