# Is search able to find accented characters entered as HTML entities (such as Fran&ccedil;ois)?

Tags: support, search, localization, unicode, html-entities

There are various ways to enter accented characters, one of them is using html.
For example, I can type Gâteaux by entering `G&acirc;teaux` or `Gâteaux`; I can type entering François by entering `Fran&ccedil;ois` or `François`. Will search find posts using either of them if I search for [Gateaux](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=Gateaux) or [Francois](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=Francois)?

I should mention that this question was inspired by a recent discussion on MathOverflow: [Formatting: Diacritics outside of Formulas](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/3076/formatting-diacritics-outside-of-formulas) (The same meta also has a closely related older discussion: [LaTeX style accents in regular text](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/290/latex-style-accents-in-regular-text).)

I have posted an [answer in the sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox/289003#289003) to be able to test this here. (The answer contains only "html-versions" of Gâteaux, François, Gödel, Pólya, Čech.) They all seem to be [working correctly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=Gateaux+Francois+Godel+Polya) with the exception of [Čech](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=Cech).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it does work, but the highlighting on the found posts doesn't work. That was what initially got me confused.

> [image]

It does search on the HTML encoded versions literally, so that is definitely not what you want.

As you see, the search for [Francois](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=Francois) yields the same post as [François](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=Fran%C3%A7ois).

Comment: You mean [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133336/search-is-too-accent-sensitive)?

Comment: Yes, indeed. Doesn't seem to work for `c` vs. `ç`.

Comment: It works as it does return the results, maybe it's just not perfect.

Comment: I see that we both had the same idea to make some tests in the sandbox [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox/289005#289005) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox/289003#289003).

Comment: I noticed it. It does work indeed. Updated my answer.

Comment: @Sha does work indeed, just confusing highlighting.

Comment: @ShadowWizard *maybe it's not just perfect* you mean that is a bug?

Comment: @rene yeah, but only a cosmetic bug, not harming the search functionality.